# Is it valid syntax to have a column name prefixed with a number, e.g., 3name?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, select-query

[image: screenshot of queries]

While toiling on a report last friday, I noticed a column that returned "3" for every row even though the data in the table said otherwise. After squinting very hard at my sql, I noticed a typo in my select list that was causing the problem.

Why does the sql parser allow the sytax below? I would have thought that this would return an error, since the column "3Name" does not exist in the table.

```
Select 3Name from Employee
```

Comment: Please include the software you are using to do this - this is not true of all flavors of SQL and even varies based on the sql client being used.

Comment: this was on microsoft sql server 2012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is interpreted as 
SELECT 3 AS NAME 
and hence the result with Column   'Name' And value 3 for all the rows.